# how to resize the wkwebview font size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to change the font size of `WKWebView` irrespective of the webkit content in iOS programming?

I am using `[Webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"resizeText(%lu)",(unsigned long)fontSize]];`

But it doesn't make any changes to the web view font size.

Comment: are you loading htmlstring in web view?

Comment: No.loading url
[self.wkWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pageUrl]];

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add `CSS` code to the content.

I had to do this one time, and here's an example from my code:

```
NSString *systemFont = [[[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.f] description] fontCSS];
NSString *boldFont = [[[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.f] description] fontCSS];
// The above fonts can be changed to your liking.
NSString *oldContent = ___; // This is the html content that was loaded.
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head>\
                   <style>\
                   img,iframe{max-width:100%%; width:auto; height:auto; display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-bottom:20px}\
                   body{%@; margin-left:24px; margin-right:24px; margin-bottom:24px}\
                   strong{%@}\
                   </style>\
                   </head><body>%@</body></html>", systemFont, boldFont, oldContent];
```

Now you use the `content` variable with your `webview`.

The `fontCSS` method is as follows, it's in an NSString category:

```
-(NSString *)fontCSS
{
    NSRange range = [self rangeOfString:@"font-family"];

    return [self substringFromIndex:range.location];
}
```

Comment: Actually Am loading a url(loadrequest method), not loadHTMLString.